# Kernel Error in anaconda Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I installed a new version of anaconda in Anaconda in Windows 10. I am getting kernel error in the Jupyter notebook. I tried many ways to fix it. BUt failed. This is the error. Can anyone please guide? Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
result = await result
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? When running the notebook? When running code? If it's the latter, can you please add a code snippet?

Comment: When I try to run the notebook, I am seeing "kernel error" on top of the notebook.